# Jung with RCP eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jung

I want to use Jung in my RCP user interface, is this possible?

the problem is that the Jung library works with JPanel and I should embed this JPanel in an Eclipse view (which works with composite) :( So how can I solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Albireo](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Albireo_Documentation) (it's a wrapper over [SWT_AWT](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/awt/SWT_AWT.html)). It's archived (i.e. not developed any more) but still works fine with current Eclipse versions.

Comment: @jean24: You can also use SWT_AWT directly, but it's much harder to get right.

Comment: in the installation page, I tried to follow the instructions (option1) but couldn't find "Source code locations" button (I'm using Galileo 3.5.2), so I put the albireo directory in the p2 (option 3), but when I want to add org.eclipse.albireo.core in the Dependencies, I can't find it :(

Comment: @jean24: If you follow the link in option 3, you'll see that you should extract plugins into `dropins` directory, not in `p2` directory.